# Getting location and external storage permissions in one application session in Android

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am adding Location and ExternalWrite permissions to my application. I would like for users to be able to acquire both permissions in one application session. Currently the application must be closed and reopened for the external write permission request dialog to appear.

Code in MainActivity is as follows,

```
    public boolean checkExternalWritePermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.title_externalwrite_permission)
                    .setMessage(R.string.text_externalwrite_permission)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_EXTERNAL_WRITE);
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
        } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_EXTERNAL_WRITE);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

...and

```
public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.title_location_permission)
                    .setMessage(R.string.text_location_permission)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, calling these from OnCreate,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
checkLocationPermission();
checkExternalWritePermission()  
}
```

after a fresh install (or a permissions reset) results in only the first function in OnCreate being called. The second is not called without the application being closed and restarted. **Question:** How can I get both permissions granted in one application session? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Merge the two functions, making one `requestPermissions()` call for all permissions. `requestPermissions()` takes a `String[]`, and you can pass more than one permission string.

Answer (score -1):

This works.

```
private boolean requestPermissions() {
    int iExtStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int iCoarseLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    int iFineLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

    if (iExtStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (iFineLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (iCoarseLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty())
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,listPermissionsNeeded.toArray
                (new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```